# Actions of $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ on algebraically closed fields and even-dimensional spheres and parallel between Galois theory and covering theory

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, galois-theory, fields, covering-spaces

It is well known that there is a parallel between Galois theory and covering theory. So I wonder whether there is a deep similarity between the following two facts:

**Artin-Schreier theorem.** The only non-trivial finite field extensions $U \supset V$ with $U$ an algebraically closed field are $U=V(\sqrt {-1}),$ so among non-trivial finite groups only $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ may "Galois-act" on an algebraically closed field.

**Corollary of Lefschetz fixed point theorem**. The only non-trivial finite coverings $U \to V$ with $U$ an *even-dimensional sphere* are given by antipodal maps, so among non-trivial finite groups only $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ may act freely on (these particular) spaces that are the universal coverings of themselves.

Unfortunately, the statement from covering theory is very particular. Maybe, there is a simple case of the first statement where the similarity may be seen even better?

Comment: P. S. This question was unsuccesully asked by me on [MSE:878944](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/878944/action-of-mathbb-z-2) two years ago.

Comment: Probably a very naive comment but the example of the Riemann sphere viewed as a compactification of the complex plane could suggest that an even dimensional sphere corresponds to the compactification of a vector space over an algebraically closed field.

Comment: Haven't we unintentionally lost the word "finite" from the statement of Artin-Schreier?

Comment: @OliverNash, thank you, I corrected!

Comment: The second fact can be proved a different way, as a special case of the fact that in an $n$ to $1$ covering $U\to V$ of (for example) finite cell complexes the Euler characteristics satisfy $\chi(U)=n\chi(V)$. Is there some sense in which an algebraically closed field, like an even-dimensional sphere, has Euler characteristic $2$?

Comment: Referring to the second fact, is there some a priori reason to restrict attention to even-dimensional spheres? After all, there are many finite groups that act freely on an odd dimensional spheres.